# Перенаправление файла с названием определенной длины

Tags: mod_rewrite, .htaccess

Приветствую!
Подскажите как в `.htaccess` создать правило перенаправления для файлов с символами `a-f0-9`, расширением `.js` и длинной 32 символа?

---

Делаю так:

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]){32}(.js)$ /script.php?s=$1 [L]
```

но переменная выдает последний символ от названия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Cript](/users/23326/cript), весь фокус в скобках.
`([a-f0-9]){32}` - так захватится один символ из набора
`([a-f0-9]{32})` - а так захватятся 32 символа из набора, поскольку в группу захвата входит квантификатор.

Плюс, на вашем месте, я бы экранировал точку. Это спецсимвол, не забывайте.
Да и вторые скобки можно опустить.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]{32})\.js$ /script.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это то что нужно!